# Laravel Collective form submit not routing properly

Tags: php, laravel

My submit button on my form using Laravel Collective is not functioning. On pressing submit, the form info stays when the form refreshes, and nothing shows up in the database. Based on the generated HTML, it seems that it's not actually going to a route, but I can't seem to figure out to make it actually go through the 'store' route.

create.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'items.store']) !!}
       <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
       </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Item Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Item;

class ItemController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'item_name'=>'required',
            'item_price'=> 'required|integer',
            'item_category' => 'required',
            'item_url' => 'required'
            ]);
        $item = new Item([
            'item_name' => $request->get('item_name'),
            'item_price'=> $request->get('item_price'),
            'item_category'=> $request->get('item_category'),
            'item_url' => $request->get('item_url')
             ]);
        $item->save();
        return redirect('/items')->with('success', 'Item has been added');
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::resource('items', 'ItemController');
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://website.com/public/items" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="...">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You might want to do some more troubleshooting here. Bring up your developer console, and watch the Network tab to make sure it's POSTing to the correct URL, and getting a proper response. Try some logging within your store function with `Log::info();`, and check the logs within `/storage/logs` for the results. Make sure `Item` has those columns as fillable, and that `$item` has an id before you return the success.

Comment: Try to change your action form to: ```action="{{route('items.create')}}"```

Comment: I can only think of a validation error. Side note: It's better to use `$request->input()` as the examples in documentation instead of `$request->get()`

Comment: @aynber Looks like trying to validate `item_price` as an integer (which I got from somewhere online) was what was throwing things off. Thanks for the note of how to log things. That helped a ton.

Comment: where are   your  html  input, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your network from the developer's tool, and the status code is 302 redirected, then it is definitely a validation error. Try by commenting on the validation rule and check if its working.